# Do I understand right condition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There is the following condition in Ruby:

```
  before_create do
    self.name = login.capitalize if name.blank?
  end
```

Does it mean that variable `self.name` will take `login` field with capitalized text only when field `name` is not empty?

Comment: Why do you ask? Does this code cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right the opposite. `self.name` will receive the value of `login.capitalize` when `name.blank?` is `true`.

You may read this condition exactly as if it were written in the 'traditional way`, like:

```
if name.empty? then
  self.name = login.capitalize
end
```

Comment: So, if `name` is empty then I will get `login`?

Comment: You haven't stated what to get when `name` is empty. Only what to get when it is not empty.